# Running a command on many files

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, files, scripting, bioinformatics

I've got a folder with many files (xyz1, xyz2, all the way up to xyz5025) and I need to run a script on every one of them, getting xyz1.faa, xyz2.faa, and so on as outputs.

The command for a single file is:

```
./transeq xyz1 xyz1.faa -table 11
```

Is there a way to do that automatically? Maybe a for-do combo?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
for file in xyz*
do
  ./transeq "$file" "${file}.faa" -table 11
done
```

This is a simple `for` loop that will iterate over every file that starts with `xyz` in the current directory and call the `./transeq` program with the filename as the first argument, the filename followed by ".faa" as the second argument, followed by "-table 11".

Comment: Or, as a one-liner: `for file in xyz*; do ./transeq "$file" "${file}.faa" -table 11; done`. I type this sort of thing all the time. And if you want to verify that the file names, etc. are getting expanded the way you want, just put an `echo` right after the `do` the first time, and then go back in your shell history and delete it the second time.

Comment: `"$file".faa` is slightly easier to type as part of an interactive one-liner, and safe because `.faa` doesn't contain any shell metacharacters that need to be quoted.

Comment: As a note, if you end up with a partial run and want to restart the loop, the `xyz*` glob would pick up .faa files as well. For bash, run `shopt -s extglob` ([reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching)), then use `for file in xyz!(*.faa) ...` to exclude the .faa files from being sent through the loop.

Answer (score 24):

If you install [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) you can do it in parallel like this:

```
parallel ./transeq {} {}.faa -table 11 ::: xyz*
```

If you program is CPU intensive it should speed up quite a bit.

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this on a `bash` command line:

```
printf '%s\n' {1..5025} | xargs -l -I {} -t ./transeq xyz{} xyz{}.faa -table 11
```

We are generating the integers from 1 to 5025 , one/line, then feeding them one-by-one to xargs, which encapsulates the integer into `{}` and then transplants it into the ./transeq command line in an appropriate manner.

Should you not have the brace-expansion facility `{n..m}` then you could invoke the `seq` utility to generate those numerics.

Or, you can always emulate the numeric generation via:

```
yes | sed -n =\;5025q | xargs ...
```

Comment: That's way over-complicated.  `for i in {1..5025}; do ./transeq "xyz$i" "xyz$i".faa -table 11; done` is way easier to think of and type.  If you want it to print commands before executing them, use `set -x`.

Comment: Yeah that's correct, but the way the OP formulated the question seemed to me that only the files with names xyz1 .. xyz5025 were of interest. So I thought if we do it using for xyz* then we need a way to reject the non-conforming files ... hence this. Ideally if the OP wants all the files in a directory processed, then why bring up the1 to 5025 thing? Just say that I want all files processed in a prescribed manner would have been sufficient.

Comment: Look at the loop I wrote.  It uses `for i in` **`{1..5025}`** to achieve *exactly* the same result as yours.  You could also write `for ((i=1 ; i<=5025 ; i++)); do ./transeq "xyz$i" "xyz$i".faa -table 11; done` in bash, but I usually use the `{a..b}` range syntax because it's faster to type.

Answer (score 4):

Using find, useful when your files are scattered inside directories

```
find -name "xyz*" -exec ./transeq {} {}.faa -table 11 \;
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have more than one core, and each invocation can run independently from the rest, you will gain quite a speedup with parallel runs.

A relatively simple way to do this is via the `-P` parameter of `xargs` - for example, if you have 4 cores:

```
echo xyz{1..5025} | \
    xargs -n 1 -P 4 -I{} /path/to/transeq xyz{} xyz{}.faa -table 11
```

The `-n 1` tells `xargs` to pick only one argument out of the list for each invocation *(by default it would pass plenty)*, and the `-P 4` tells it to spawn 4 processes at the same time - when one dies, a new one is spawned.

IMHO, you don't need to install GNU parallel for this simple case - `xargs` suffices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xarg`

`ls | xargs -L 1 -d '\n' your-desired-command`

`-L 1` causes pass 1 item at a time

`-d '\n'` make output of `ls` is split'ed based on new line.